# SQL query for search criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my table there are codes which are basically decimal values. For example the code column contains data like `001.0`, `00.10`, `002.0`, `00.20` etc. I have to write a SQL query which shows following result while searching the code values from UI:

- If the user searches `0010`, I have to show all the values `001.0`, `00.10`
- if the user searches `001.0`, I have to show values like `001.0`, `001.1` etc.
- if the user searches `00.10`, I have to show value `00.10`, `00.12` etc.

Please help me in writing SQL query for the above criteria.

Comment: Do the codes always consist of only 4 digits and a (randomly placed) decimal point? Is the point always present?

Comment: What should be the result if the user entered `001.1`?

Comment: Are the rules "if no `.` is specified, all digits must exactly match, and `.` is ignored" and "if `.` is specified, then an exact match must occur up until the last non-zero digit"? Please try to carefully describe the matching rules - the above two are my best guess based on your limited examples. The more thought you can put into describing them, the more likely that we'll come up with answers for the overall problem.

Comment: Andiry:The code always contain decimal values.maximum lenght of code is 8 digit.It can be fewer also.If the user enters 001.0 the result returned would be like %code%.The main problem is when the user enters the value without decimal in serach criteria like 0010 then the result returned should be all values which have 0010 meand 001.0,00.101,001.1 etc

Comment: which algorithm are you using if any ?

Comment: `If the user enters 001.0 the result returned would be like %code%` – you mean, the search term should be matched against middle parts of the codes as well? Like if the user entered `001.0`, it should match a code like `1001.01`? It is also not entirely clear about `0010`. Why does `001.1` match `0010` (as per your comment)? I second Damien's suggestion: please edit your question and add more examples that would show the rules clearly.

Comment: input:0010 o/p:00.10,0.010,001.0 that meand if in we take code column and remove the dot it should match with the search criteria i/p. for eg if u remove dot all will show 0010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything is entirely clear about your rules, but I hope that the following will serve you as a passable starting point at least.

Apparently, the search term should be processed in two ways, depending on whether it contains the decimal point. So first you need to know whether the point is present or not. That could be done using the `CHARINDEX()` function: if it returns 0, the decimal point is absent from the search term, otherwise it is there. Thus, your complete condition will be structured like this:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('.', @SearchTerm) = 0 AND … /* condition to match '0010'-like input */
   OR CHARINDEX('.', @SearchTerm) > 0 AND … /* condition to match input containing '.' */
```

The condition to search for the term without `.` might look like this:

```
REPLACE(Code, '.', '') = @SearchTerm  /* or maybe LIKE @SearchTerm + '%'? */
```

The condition for the case when the search term does contain `.` seems to me trickier than the previous one, but anyway, here's what I came up with:

```
Code LIKE REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') + '%'
```

How it works, step by step, using `'001.0'` and `'00.10'` as examples:

```
Initial value                                                   '001.0'  '00.10'
REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '0', ' ')                                  '  1. '  '  .1 '
RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '0', ' '))                           '  1.'   '  .1'
REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')        '001.'   '00.1'
REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') + '%'  '001.%'  '00.1%'
```

So, as you can see, the expression evaluates to a mask that should satisfy your rules for search terms containing `.`.

Pulling all the conditions together, we get the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('.', @SearchTerm) = 0 AND REPLACE(Code, '.', '') = @SearchTerm
   OR CHARINDEX('.', @SearchTerm) > 0 AND
      Code LIKE REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') + '%'
```

Comment: If dotless searches are common then performance could be improved by having an extra `UndottedCode` column that can be indexed.  A trigger could maintain the value based on changes to the `Code` column.  Denormalized For Performance!(sm)

Comment: @user92546: Good point. A computed column might be an even better option.